# installing Opencv on mac os x 10.6 for use with Xcode 3.2.2 project

Tags: xcode, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV on my Mac (OS X v10.6.3) for use with an Xcode (v 3.2.2) project.  I have downloaded the current OpenCV tar ball from SourceForge, and am following these installation instructions:  http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port (scroll down to the section called Using the OpenCV libraries in an Xcode OS X project).  Unfortunately, the instructions were written for Xcode 3.1.1 and so there are some differences between that version and 3.2.2.  So I have a couple of questions about the installation, which I hope someone who has been down this road before can answer for me...

First, The 7th - 10th bullet points say to add a new Group to the Project and include some specific files from /usr/local/lib (libcxcore.dylib, libcvaux.dylib, libcv.dylib, libhighgui.dylib, and libml.dylib).  I cannot find any such path on my mac.  And I cannot find the files via Finder, either.  Any idea where to look for them?

Second, Way back up on the first bullet point it had me create a new Xcode project using the Command Line Utility template.  There was, however, no mention of which "type" to select (C, C++, Foundation, Core Data, etc.).  I chose C, but would like to know if this is correct?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested ... I was able to successfully install OpenCV, by first installing Macports and then following the steps listed under "option 1" in the Willowgarage link from above.  Note there is a comment in those instructions that says something like "on Mac OS" the /usr/... path is actually /opt/... (which is why I wasn't finding the /usr/ path).  And my "test" Command Line program did work, so I guess they type of "C" was ok.

So now I'm off to experiment with some of the OpenCV functions, which I hope will provide me the ability to accomplish some things I haven't been able to do using CIFilters...

Answer (score 0):

I am trying out OpenCV on my MacBook laptop (OS X v10.6.6) for use with an Xcode (v 3.2). I wasn't sure about the 7th to 10th bullet points since the names changed so I just added the ones I found for OpenCV (v 2.2.0).

- libopencv_video.dylib
- libopencv_objdetect.dylib
- libopencv_ml.dylib
- libopencv_legacy.dylib
- libopencv_imgproc.dylib
- libopencv_gpu.dylib
- libopencv_contrib.dylib
- libopencv_highgui.dylib
- libopencv_flann.dylib
- libopencv_features2d.dylib
- libopencv_core.dylib
- libopencv_calib3d.dylib